# React: is it possible to render a component object that was created with "new"?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an application where the user can dynamically alter the layout of the page. There are two interfaces. Together they provide a collection of components that can be used to build the layout:

```
export interface IComponentProvider {
    key : string;
    displaylabel : string;
    description ?: string;
    render(): React.ReactNode;
}

export interface IComponentCollection {
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: IComponentProvider, key: string) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    get(key: string): IComponentProvider | undefined;
    has(key: string): boolean;
    readonly size: number;
}
```

Notes:

- `IComponentProvider` can be implemented by a `React.Component`. It is actually a special component that has a key and a displaylabel. The key is used to identify the component in the collection. The displaylabel is used to give it a friendly name. (So the user will see 'User details' instead of 'userDetailPanelId132').
- `Map<string, React.Component>` implements `IComponentCollection`. Actually, in most cases I'll be using a Map for implementing it.

There are two classes that should be used for rendering the layouts. There is a `DynamicLayoutConfiguration` class that defines the structure of the layout. It stores a tree of component types and component references. For example:

```
{
  type: "tabs"
  items: [
     {type:"tab", title:"First tab", 
      items:[
        {
         type:"component", 
         key:"masterComponent1"}
     ]},
     {type:"tab", title:"Second tab", 
      items:[
        {
         type:"component", 
         key:"detailPanel1"}
     ]},
  ]
}
```

The layout configuration is not a component, and it does not contain the actual components. Only they keys of those components. The configuration can be saved/loaded. This provides persistence for the layout.

The last part is the `DynamicLayout` component that gets a collection and a configuration, and it should be able to render the layout:

```
interface IDynamicLayoutProps {
    configuration: DynamicLayoutConfiguration;
    collection: IComponentCollection;
}


export class DynamicLayout extends React.PureComponent<IDynamicLayoutProps> {
   public render() {
        /* Here we should render, using this.props.configuration and this.props.components */
        return null; // ???
   }
}
```

The above example configuration should render something like this:

```
<Tabs>
   <TabList>
     <Tab>First tab</Tab>
     <Tab>Second tab</Tab>
   </TabList>
   <TabPanel>{this.props.components.get('masterComponent1').render()}</TabPanel>
   <TabPanel>{this.props.components.get('detailPanel1').render()}</TabPanel>
</Tabs>
```

Why I need this: because the same data must be presented to the user in various ways, and I want the users to be able to define their own layouts. There is a separate layout editor where the user can create UI component tree structures with containers, rows, columns, tabs, accordions etc. and they can insert components into this layout (from the component collection).

Here comes the problem. Obviously, the component collection needs to be created before the user could create the layout configuration. So for example, if I have a component called `DetailPanel`:

```
export class DetailPanel extends React.Component<...>{...}
```

Then in theory, I could do this:

```
const components = new Map<string,IComponentProvider>();
const detailPanel = new DetailPanel(detailPanelProps);
components.set(detailPanel.key, detailPanel);
```

And then open the layout editor for the user where he can use the DetailPanel (if he wants to). But notice that `DetailPanel` was created using the new keyword.

How can I render a component that was created that way? Obviously, if I just return that object from the render method, then I get an 'Objects are not valid as react child' error. I have tried to return the result of render():

```
<TabPanel>
  {this.props.components.get(componentKey).render()}
</TabPanel>
```

While this DOES render the component, but it DOES NOT call `componentDidMount` nor `componentWillUnmount`, generally it is defective and cannot be used.

I think that I should not create these components manually with `new DetailPanel()`. 
But I have no idea how else could it be? How can I create a general "collection of components" without creating the components? If I have to create them manually, then how can I properly render them?

**UPDATE**: As @Berouminum pointed out, there is no good solution. One can only render elements with JSX or with React.createElement. None of those will actually create the objects right away, only when they are needed. It means that either I create them with React.createElement and then I'm not able to access the key and displaylabel properties, or create them with the `new` keyword (normal object construction) but then I won't be able to render them properly.

The best workaround I have found so far is to change IComponentProvider to have a "createElement" method instead of a render method:

```
export interface IComponentProvider {
    key : string;
    displaylabel : string;
    description ?: string;
    createElement(): React.ReactElement;
}
```

Any component that wishes to implement this interface, the createElement method can be implemented trivially:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component<IProps,IState> impements IComponentProvider {
   public get key() { return this.calculateKey(); }
   public get displaylabel() { return this.calculateDisplaylabel(); }
   public get description() { return this.calculateDescription(); }
   public createElement() {
       return React.createElement(ExampleComponent,this.props, null);
   }
}
```

With this, it is possible to use key/displaylabel properties, call methods on the object, and render it properly:

```
const exampleComponent = new ExampleComponent(props);
/* It is possible to use its properties here. */
components.set(exampleComponent.key, exampleComponent);
/* It is also possible to render it PROPERLY, all lifecycle methods called correctly. */
class SomeContainer extends React.Component<...> {
   ...
   public render() {
       return <div>
                ....
              {exampleComponent.createElement()}
              ...
       </div>;

   }
```

Of course, this solution is also faulty, because objects will be constructed multiple times (once manually with the new keywords, and possibly multiple times created by React when the element is needed). So the object that is rendered will actually be a different instance. But so far, this is the best workaround I have found. It is reusable and general enough.

**UPDATE 2**: The provided solution is completely broken if I try to use it with MobX. It is because the rendered component and the original are different objects. If I set an observable on the original object, then it won't have any effect on the rendered object. There is a very messy workaround but probably it doesn't worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React there are 2 ways to instantiate a component.

via JSX

```
const Comp = <Component prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} />;
```

via `React.createElement('element', props, children)`

```
const Comp = React.createElement(Component, { prop1, prop2 }, null);
```

The created component can afterwards be rendered by returning it from a render function (just like any other element). You should not try to invoke render manually.

I've build a small example for you. You can render both functionless-components and class-components this way. ComponentDidMount also get's called

```
const A = () => <div>A</div>;

class B extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('I mounted!');
    }

    render() {
        return <div>B</div>
    }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const map = new Map();
        map.set('A', {
            displayLabel: 'Label A',
            description: 'Description A',
            component: A()
        });
        map.set('B1', {
            displayLabel: 'Label B1',
            description: 'Description B1',
            component: <B />
        });
        map.set('B2', {
            displayLabel: 'Label B2',
            description: 'Description B2',
            component: React.createElement(B)
        });

        const {
            displayLabel,
            description,
            component
        } = map.get('A');

        return (
            <div>
                <p>{displayLabel}</p>
                <p>{description}</p>
                {component}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just missing one more thing. Let's say that I put these elements into a map. It will be a map of elements, not a map of objects. I won't be able to access their displaylabel and description properties, or anything else. But I need to access those - without them, I won't be able to create a layout editor (the end user needs to see the displaylabel). How can I define a map that allows access to both the elements and the displaylabel/description properties?

Comment: @nagylzs You can just wrap your component with an object which contains your additional information. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I wish they were string constants. These properites are implemented as property getters. I'm going to accept your answer tomorrow anyway, because I don't think there is a better  solution. :-(

Comment: In other words: your example fails to work when the additional information is a property of the object. Simply because React.createElement does not create the object. It makes all of the properties inaccessible, and it will be impossible to put them into a collection and use them in a layout editor.